# What does "sudo iw dev [interface] scan" do?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm having problem with my wifi adapter so I emailed customer support. The rep told me to provide him with the output for `iwconfig`. Then he told me to send him the output for `iw dev [interface] scan`.

I was not permitted to run that command so I had to add `sudo` and redirect the output to a text file. I read the text file but there's a lot of information in there that I don't understand. Can someone explain to me what `sudo iw dev [interface] scan` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does `iw dev [interface] scan` except with the access which root has.

What does a web search on `Ubuntu man iw` tell us? We look in  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/iw.8.html and see `dev [interface]` shows information just about that particular specified interface, and `scan` looks for nearby WiFi access points.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880517/2909179 gives a good example of the result after a little text processing; in the aforementioned example, that user collected the name, frequency, signal strength, and encryption type of the WiFi access points near him.

It's safe to run.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the command.